# Google pubsub to Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible for a bucket in cloud storage to receive data/messages  from pubSub? if yes then how??

Currently i am publishing messages to pubsub
and i want to use pull delivery type (for that i have to provide endpoint URL for the bucket, which i couldn't find anywhere)

I found this [somewhere in there docs](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/bucket-name/)

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

[Pubsub subscription for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/cloudstorage) is now supported. You no longer need any dataflow or computing resources to transfer the data to GCS.
[image]

This subscription also offers different options

1. file format
2. file name prefix/suffix
3. batch duration
4. maximum size per file

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. GCS only accepts uploads of complete files via HTTP. You could build a small app that took incoming Pub/Sub messages and uploading them as separate GCS objects or batch them into groups of messages and upload those to GCS, but there's no such built-in functionality.

Can I ask you more about your use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: old question, but the basic idea is that I need instant logs from cloudsql. Sink to bucket only works on per hour basis. Pub sub is instant. I read my k8s cluster logs from the bucket already. It would make sense to redirect pubsub logs to the same bucket as well. So in this case, it is just a crutch to retrieve the logs from databases in the timely manner.

Comment: @user3081519 you can use Cloud Dataflow to read from PubSub and Write to GCS